# Why wont the text in the text-boxes save to my List?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, repeater

Having trouble to get the text out of the text-box and into my `List<T>`. Help would be much appreciated.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rptQuestionnaireQuestions.Items)
{
    TextBox txtResponse = (TextBox)ri.FindControl("txtResponse");

    if (txtResponse != null)
    {
        responses.Add(new QuestionnaireUserAnswer()
        {
            questionId = questionId,
            answerId = 5,
            freeText = txtResponse.Text
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: and what happens?  Do you enter the `if` statement?

Comment: Yes, I enter the `if` statement and the questionId and the answerId are added; no text though!

Comment: In which method are you running the above statement? Dynamically generated controls do not retain their contents during/after postback; I've had issues with similar scenarios and there's not much warning about this.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are only checking wether Textbox control is available or not by checking for null, but you are not cecking for Empty Text

**Solution :** You can check for EmptyText in `TextBox` control using `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method

Try This:

```
if (txtResponse != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtResponse.Text))
{
    responses.Add(new QuestionnaireUserAnswer()
    {
        questionId = questionId,
        answerId = 5,
        freeText = txtResponse.Text
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem was actually `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` being missed from the `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if( Srting.IsNullorEmpty("Your string text"))
{ 
//code here
}
```